# How to disconnect child props from Parent's state passed in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have seen a lot of questions regarding updating a parent's state from a child component, however my question is just the opposite. I have a component, a modal editing window, used for modifying objects stored in a parent's state. 
I only want to have these changes copied to the parent if the user saves these changes, which is handled by a function I pass to the child component. 
Currently, anytime I make a change to the prop.obj in the child, the change is picked up by the parent on re-render.

here is an example of one of my change handlers

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.state.childobj.myvaluetochange = e.target.value
}
```

In my parent, as stated, I pass obj to the child from the parent's state like so

```
<MyComponent obj={this.state.obj} />
```

to summarize:

I send a state object to a child

The child uses this.props.obj to use this obj in a form and uses handlers to update

When changes are picked up in the child, they reflect on the parent's state object on update - I don't want this unless they choose to save. (this is handled by a function passed in from the parent)

to clarify, I want the state obj passed to the child to act as a completely separate object when it lives in the child. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I would simply clone the state you pass and treat it as a local state of this component.

Comment: See, that was my first thought. I created a clone of the object I passed in and set it to my state, but it still sets the parent's state. Before this I just set the prop to the child's state, but same effect. `this.state = { childobj: this.props.obj}`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are mutating the given prop.

To avoid this you should create new instance of "this.props.obj". Probably you want to do it in "componentWillMount" and "componentWillReceiveProps" lifecycle methods. To create new instance of object you can use Object.assign or spread operators.

Comment: Yea, I attempted this in ComponentWillMount (isn't this depreciated?) and am still having my issue. As I stated in the comment above, I think there's more to this as based off of the docs and everyone's suggestion, my changes should not be getting back to the parent. Thanks for the help, I'll keep digging!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a link to the parent object and then mutating the state which will reflect in the parent. An easy way around this is to create a new version of it by using the spread operator to create a new object:

```
this.state = {childObj: {...this.props.obj}}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion. Based off of that info, it appears something else is going on as even when I create another copy, it still reflects on the parent. I have triple checked my passed in functions, even removed references to the child's obj on save, still having this issue. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: On change you seem to be updating the parent object (via props), you need to use your components version by referencing this.state.childobj.myvaluetochange

Comment: Yea I saw that, the actual code does reference my child's obj. I'll update the code snippet for clarity. Thanks for pointing that out! Could have been one of those gotchas.